# How can I get my Excel VSTO Add-in to update cells when the spreadsheet window is minimized?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am currently working on a VSTO Add-in for Excel. We have code that can update a cell's value whenever a message from a cloud application is received. I have found that whenever the spreadsheet window is minimized, the cell will not be updated whenever the code to update the cell is executed.

We use the [Range.Value2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2) property to update a cell's value. I have verified that the code that updates a cell's value is in fact getting executed whenever the window is minimized. The problem is that the cell's value is not updated whenever the Range.Value2 property is used while the spreadsheet is minimized.

Here is the code that updates the cell values:

```
private void OnLinkedCellValueChanged(object sender, IEnumerable<CellLinkModel> cells)
{
    foreach (CellLinkModel cell in cells)
    {
        Worksheet worksheet = GetWorksheet(cell.WorkSheetId);

        if (worksheet == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Range range = cell.GetRange();
        if (range == null)
        {
            range = (Range) worksheet.Cells[cell.Row, cell.Column];
            cell.SetRange(range);
        }

        range.Value2 = cell.CellValue;
    }
}
```

What I see is that the code does get executed, but the cell value is not updated when Range.Value2 is set while the spreadsheet window is minimized. Can anybody tell me why this happens and provide a work-around to get the cell value to update?

Comment: Have a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/1361290/excel-2013-2016-not-updating-values-while-workbook-is-minimized

Comment: Thanks for the link @RandRandom. I'd like to understand why this is happening. Do you have any idea why this happens and why toggling the _Application.ScreenUpdating property whenever the Window is resized fixes the issue?

Comment: No never figured that out, was just happy that I found a solution. My guess would be that there is a form of suspense layout rendering in place and when restoring the window no one bothered to update the layout - which the screenupdating does

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue by using the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1361290/excel-2013-2016-not-updating-values-while-workbook-is-minimized) posted by the user @RandRandom in their comment to my question. What may be happening is that while Excel is minimized, layout rendering is paused. Any update to a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))'s value during this period will update the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object, but will not update the screen. Once the spreadsheet's window is restored and rendering is turned back on, a re-render does not take place. Performing an operation that would cause a re-render, such as scrolling until the stale cell is no longer visible, then scrolling back will cause the cell to be rendered with the correct value, since the [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) object itself actually has the correct value.

To work around the issue programmatically, I subscribed to the [AppEvents_Event.WindowResize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.windowresize?view=excel-pia) event. Ideally there would be a way to invalidate the spreadsheet to cause a re-render that we could use in the event handler, but there's not one that I am aware of. What I do in the event handler, is set the [_Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating?view=excel-pia) property equal to itself. Setting this property causes a re-render. The code can be found below.

Where appropriate in your application, subscribe to the [AppEvents_Event.WindowResize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.windowresize?view=excel-pia) event:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WindowResize += OnWindowResize;
```

In the event handler, set the [_Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating?view=excel-pia) property equal to itself:

```
private void OnWindowResize(Workbook Wb, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window window)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating;
}
```